Where does the finger command takes the information about the write permissions of the tty's
I'm trying to create my own finger command in C in Linux Mint. Studying the real finger command I've understood that the asterisk that the commands put when using the short output format left the tty is when one of the user has the write permission disabled, the permission used to send and receive messages between tty's I assume, that can be enabled with the  mesg y command.
The point of my question is, where does finger gets the information about the write permissions of the tty? I've tryied looking into the utmp file but I can't find something relevant :(
Also, if I disable the write permission on the tty connected with the GUI, why does the finger  command put the asterisk on the pts/0 entry, instead near my tty?
like
matteo      tty7     2:40  Apr 29 16:10 (:0)
matteo      *pts/0         Apr 29 17:20

thanks in advance and sorry if I wrote something incorrectly, it's my first time going this deep in Linux :)

The answer to your second question depends on exactly how you disabled write permission on the tty connected with the GUI. Did you run mesg n in a terminal emulator running inside your GUI?

@StephenKitt yes I run mesg n inside the terminal emulator

OK, I’ve updated the answer to address that.

The write permissions are determined by looking at the permissions on the terminal device file itself; in your case:
ls -l /dev/tty7 /dev/pts/0

Writable terminals will show up as crw--w--w-, non-writable terminals as crw-------.
Regarding the use of pts/0 instead of tty7, your terminal emulator doesn’t use the VT associated with your desktop environment (tty7), it uses its own tty. So mesg n run in the terminal emulator only affects the terminal’s tty, not the VT. If you run tty inside the terminal emulator, you’ll see it uses /dev/pts/0.
